# Django registration-profile - next step to a user profile

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I have installed the django-registration app to my project. After a successful log in step, I am redirecting the user to `localhost:8000/` - this is my default testing host and port. And I am displaying somewhere on the page, the `username` of the logged in `user`.

What I want to do now is that when I click the `username` some options like `edit profile` or `change password` will appear. My questions are the following:

1. Should I create another model (inside another new app) containing fields like profile photo, gender, birthday etc and add a foreign key to the `User` model from `django.contrib.auth.models` ? Or should I modify the model from django-registration to add some additional fields but which I do not ask for at registration phase and only update them later?
2. if I want my `profile edit` feature to be at `/accounts/edit`, which would be the best practice to do it? to edit the URLconf of my project and add a line like `(r'^accounts/edit$',.....)` just before `(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),` ?

I hope I made myself clear. I'm trying to figure out which would be the best approach before coding, as I am new to Django... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I find it's easier to decouple the profile table from the auth table.   Just like you mentioned you can use a foreign key relationship to link that profile to the user.  You can also apply a lambda inside of your profile table to automatically create a profile when a new user object is created.

Inside your template you can link to the profile page dynamically based on the current authenticated party by using

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<a href="/user_profile/{{ request.user.id }}">Update Profile</a>
{% endif %}
```

user_profile being the name of your app which holds your user_profile table.  That way when the request is made you use the regular expression for the current user id (similar to the polls example provided by django) to get the id number of the currently logged in user than inside the views you just query the database for that particular user.

views.py

```
def myView(request, user_id):
    userProfile = UserProfile.objects.get(user.pk=user_id)
```

This is a high level example to give an idea of one way to accomplish it.

Comment: `You can also apply a lambda inside of your profile table to automatically create a profile when a new user object is created. ` - How to do this specifically?

Comment: I understood what you ment. But a user will simply see his profile at `localhost:8000/username` . What I want is the link `localhost:8000/accounts/edit` for editing their personal info (gender, age etc). So I should create another app like "user_profile" and add a model which I have to link to the User model

Comment: no in your views.py you would just need one view for handling edits, but that will also use the same logic mentioned above to make an update to their profile page. (I'm assuming this page is just a form maybe prepopulated with data already on file)  So just to recap, one view which dynamically queries and displays profile info in a template and another that displays the update profile form template.

Comment: so to answer your question yes you would create another app named user_profile with it's own model, views, url files.  I would put the profile page and update profile page in the views of the user_profile app.  Then again, I know a lot of sites like to put the username in the url, my example would look more like http://localhost/user_profile/1 (and increment by user_profile added)

Comment: Thanks Chris. I am following the pattern of Instagram (URLs, some templates, some features etc) because the site is built in Django. So I'm trying to make a cheap replica just to make myself confortable in Django